# error mounting exfat usb

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I've got a USB key i'm having trouble mounting on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

When I attach it I can see it as `/dev/sdb1`, `type=exfat`, it's got a label and a name.  But when I try and mount it I get:

```
FUSE exfat 1.1.0
ERROR: unknown entry type 0xc5
```

What are my next steps to mount this key or confirm it's faulty?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question while looking for my own mysterious `ERROR: unknown entry type 0xc1` running `FUSE exfat 1.2.7` which I could not really solve yet.

In my case everything seemed to work fine (AFAIK) until I mounted the exFAT-volume on a windows (8.1) system for the first time which mounted it without any complaint but showed an empty filesystem (no entries) but with some considerable space (about 66% which was about the amount of data copied onto it before on a linux machine) miraculously occupied.

I also found an [issue on GH](https://github.com/relan/exfat/issues/33) revolving around `unknown entry type 0x96` which started to let me think that the hex-code itself (`0xc5`, `0x96` or `0xc1`) is of minor importance, but something (not necessary the same) underlying went possibly wrong.

from the discussion on GH I learned that the following commands might help to get a clearer picture what might be going on (make sure to specify the correct device!):

- `dumpexfat /dev/sdb1`
- `mount.exfat-fuse -d /dev/sdb1`
- `exfatfsck /dev/sdb1`

In my case, all these commands exited with the exact same error-message described above.

Also in the issue it is recommended to upgrade if running v1.1.0 as you are so that might already help in your case.

I yet have to take a closer look at what may have caused the corruption in my case as I have a suspicion that it might be related to the way I formatted the filesystem (`mkfs.exfat` with individual volume-ID and name)...

**EDIT:** was able to reproduce what I wrote above. Certain characters in custom volume-names seem to cause the behaviour I observed. [Issue #89 openend on GH ...](https://github.com/relan/exfat/issues/89)

**EDIT2:** `FUSE exfat 1.2.8` seems to successfully fix Issue #89 so I'd recommend to upgrade to that version (or newer once released in the future...).

Comment: I had experienced this same issue on my Linux laptop mounting a exfat formatted SD card from my Sony Xperia Android phone.  I have found that after a recent update (early August 2018), android's formatting of the SD card now mounts on my Linux machine.  The only thing that changed was my android update at which time I tried re-formatting the same SD card.  I'm running `community/exfat-utils 1.2.7-1` on my Arch linux machine.